# Automatic mobile view from desktop browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Hello I have created a mobile web site with MVC5, so when you enter it from the desktop browser you get a very bad image. Problem: When you enter the site from the desktop browser, for example by pressing Chrome browser f12, the mobile image is obtained. Can you do this automatically when you enter the site? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a "*very bad image*" on desktop if your site works well on mobile - at worst you should be getting a simple scale up of your mobile site. But the question is, how is your 'mobile site' created? Are you using a separate subdomain for the mobile site, media queries, etc? Assuming the former, you could just do a forcible redirect.

Comment: No, I just typed mobile css. I want to show the desktop auto mobile. There is no subdomain name.